# mp4 muxing problems on dm365 board

Tags: ffmpeg, mpeg-4, mux

I happen to be stuck with strange TI codec issues while encoding video. To cut story short - the encoded data which is generated by TI mpeg4 codecs are not 'understood' by nothing else, but VLC and media classic player.

After really long googling and several seasons I face to you stackoverlowers to help me understand what is wrong in the encoded frame headers, because I really fail to find any answers.

AviDemux 2.6.1 opens and remux-es video data without problems. So there is hope to understand whats is wrong with mp4 generated data...

I would really appreciate any help from mp4 gurus out there...

[the link to the problem file](http://speedy.sh/Dk5CQ/last-recoded.mp4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that TI DM365 codec 'mpeg4enc' produces invalid data, not ready to use outright in the container. Codec 'mpe4hdenc' does it right